# Fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 boots only in text mode

Tags: ubuntu, boot, text-mode

I have a HP pavilion 15z with Windows 8. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on it (graphical intallation) and when I rebooted it at the end, it only goes into text mode. When trying `startx` it shows a "fatal server error: No screen found".

When trying to use the "Try Ubuntu" option of the LiveUSB it also boots only in text mode.

Comment: do you use nvidia card? and does the error say enything else?

Comment: the laptop have a radeon 8330g if am not mistaken, and this is what the error when i tried to run "startx" http://imgur.com/x30Tks5 http://imgur.com/j1sDige http://imgur.com/x30Tks5

Comment: Please delete the contents of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, run `startx`, and then post the contents of that file after `X` fails to start.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. how can i save the content of the log and post it here? when i boot into ubuntu is in text mode only and am not to good at using text mode..

Comment: @DarthAndroid this is the content of the Xorg http://pastebin.com/hBQQwWX0

Comment: There's definately something weird going on with your graphics card and linux: `(EE) VESA(0): V_BIOS address 0x0 out of range`. I don't think I've seen the `vesa` driver fail like that before, which suggests that either the graphics card or another piece of hardware isn't fully supported. (VESA is the common, standardized interface for graphics cards, commonly associated with "safemode"; It's not the prettiest, but it should almost always work)

Answer (score 0):

One likely solution to your problem is to delete the *xorg.conf*.

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Probably would be backup the file too, just in case.

<sub>[Reference](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1980810)</sub>

Comment: So how about `sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak`

Comment: I tried to deleted but theres no xorg.conf in that folder.. theres a xorg.conf.failsafe thought..